# When is it necessary to use a capital letter in the beginning of the sentence?

Tags: правописание

In English we have to use a capital letter in the following cases:

- Beginning of sentence
- Names (people or places)
- Pronoun first-person singular (I)

What are the rules for capital letters in Russian language comparing to these three rules in English?

Answer (score 7):

Basically, capital letter is required in the beginning of a sentence and in names (people, places, books, etc.).

There is a tricky case with singular "вы", which can be capitalized to show respect (note that plural "вы" is capitalized only in the beginning of a sentence).

Also with multi-word names (e.g. name of a book), only first letter is capitalized, not first letter of each word as in English.

Another difference with English will be that not everything that considered to be a name in English is considered to be a name in Russian. For example, names of languages and nations and  are *not* capitalized in Russian. I think it might have to do something with most of those being adjectives in Russian (though it's just an opinion).

Comment: Thank you. What about the pronoun я, is it not supposed to be capitalized as happens to be in English with the pronoun I?

Comment: no, "я" is only capitalized in the beginning if a sentence and if it's first word of some title, e.g. "Я и мои котики"

Answer (score 6):

Personal pronoun ***I*** is never capitalised (unless positioned at the beginning of a sentence):

***Я изучаю китайский язык, и чем больше я его изучаю, тем больше у меня вопросов.***

Names of countries are capitalised, but not names of nations and/or languages (it used to be so a couple of centuries ago, but not nowadays). Forms of address and titles are not capitalised, either.

***Из всех языков, пани и панство, мадам, мадмуазели, месье, леди, джентльмены, дамы, господа и товарищи, мне наименее симпатичны английский и русский, а из всех известных мне людей наименее вежливы в обиходе - носители советского русского.***

Days of weeks and months are not capitalised:

***Сегодня - вторник, двадцать пятое апреля.***

Abstract nouns (mainly those capitalised in modern English to imitate archaic style and/or to express 'philosophical uniqueness' of the concept they are referring to, or those normally capitalised in 'capitalisation boom' of the 17th-18th centuries following [Hart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Hart_%28spelling_reformer%29)'s recommendation are not capitalised, either):

***Относительная истина не противоречит абсолютной истине.***

As for words for G-d, deities and religious holidays / events, their capitalisation is guarded either by the rules applied for personal names or by a writer's personal beliefs.